# Flutter: Is it bad to put streams in a StreamBuilder directly?

Tags: flutter, dart, optimization

Currently, my StreamBuilders look something like this:

```
        StreamBuilder(
              stream:  Firestore.instance.collection("events").snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            ...
        })
```

However, while researching an unrelated topic, I read this

> it's a good idea to move the
> Firestore.instance.collection('events').snapshots() to initState(),
> save the reference to the stream in a private field and use that it
> StreamBuilder. Otherwise, at every build() you may be creating a new
> stream. You should be ready for build() calls that happen many times
> per second, whatever the reason.

Is this something I should worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `StreamBuilder` is inside a `build` method, which I assume is the situation, Flutter framework will definitely can call it for different reasons, possibly many times, depending on your code. So yes, you should create your stream somewhere earlier and only assign to `stream`, so that it is not unnecessarily re-created. For example:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _myStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      },
    );
  }
}
```